# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED after updating package name

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-manifest

I know this question has been asked a lot, but the answers I'm seeing don't seem to be helping me.

I refactored my package name after copying a repo template. Now I am getting this message:

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED
Installation failed due to: 'null'
```

This is what I get out of Logcat:

```
2020-05-20 12:41:01.983 15343-15343/? E/studio.deploy: Could not get package user id: /system/bin/run-as: unknown package: com.venuenext.southernalbertajubilee
2020-05-20 12:41:01.997 15343-15343/? E/studio.deploy: Could not find apks for package: com.venuenext.southernalbertajubilee
2020-05-20 12:41:03.000 1835-1852/? E/installd: Failed to delete /data/app/vmdl655566087.tmp: No such file or directory
```

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding, invalidate cache and restart, syncing with files and with gradle system, and I don't have uppercased characters in my package name, but can't shake this error.

Any suggestions? I'm pretty sure my manifest looks correct:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.venuenext.southernalbertajubilee">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup, android:theme"
        tools:targetApi="n">
        <!--TODO: Setup:: Update 'icon' && 'roundIcon' with your new app icons. If needed generate icons from https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html-->
        <activity
            android:name="com.venuenext.southernalbertajubilee.ArenaActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!--Localytics Test Mode IntentFilter-->
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="@string/ll_app_schema" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- This intent filter is used to handle deep links, allowing them to launch the app -->
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="@string/dyc_deeplink_scheme" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.venuenext.southernalbertajubilee.FCMService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Set custom default icon. This is used when no icon is set for incoming notification messages. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
                android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
            <!--TODO: Setup:: Update above resource with the app icon.-->

            <!-- Set color used with incoming notification messages. This is used when no color is set for the incoming
                 notification message. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
                android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

EDIT: I've also tried clearing `.gradle/caches`. No dice.

Comment: if it was working before you changed....then just change them back....clean and rebuild...then start changing one at a time...i had similar issue and this method solved it..hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I ended up scrapping all my changes and starting over from scratch. Updating the package name again to the *exact same name* didn't give me any issues.

Kind of sucks, but it seems like the answer is "try again". ‍♂️